# Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\UserController::successResponse() (500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postman, lumen

I am so confused by this error because this is my first time in back end subject , our instructor didn't included the CRUD operations on the video he provided so I decided to discover all by myself then I came up with this error on POST operation

HTTP - CONTROLLER -  USER CONTROLLER PHP

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
Class UserController extends Controller {
  private $request;
public function __construct(Request $request){
  $this->request = $request;
}
public function getUsers(){ 
  $users = User::all();
  return response()->json($users, 200);
}

public function add(Request $request ){
  $rules = [
  'first_name' => 'required|max:20',
  'last_name' => 'required|max:20',
  // 'gender' => 'required|in:Male,Female',
  ];
  $this->validate($request,$rules);
  $user = User::create($request->all());
  return $this->successResponse($user,
 Response::HTTP_CREATED);
  }
}
```

MODEL - USER PHP

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model{
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'students';
// column sa table
protected $fillable = [
'first_name', 'last_name'
];
}
```

ROUTES - WEB PHP

```
<?php

/** @var \Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router $router */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It is a breeze. Simply tell Lumen the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->get('/users',['uses' => 'UserController@getUsers']);


$router->post('/postUsers', 'UserController@add'); // create new user record
```

This is the all good I cant identify where the error occured or I have something miss to put

I just want to run the POST in postman to add data on column because I think POST is updating the database

so this is the data that I want to add

```
{
    "first_name": "Lorem",
    "last_name": "Ipsum"
}
```

Comment: Your `UserController`, and by extension Laravel's `Controller` Class, doesn't have a `successResponse` method. Where did you see that code? You can do a simple `return response()->json(['user' => $user], 200);` to return an `HTTP 200` success response, similar to what you're already doing in `getUsers()`

Comment: Did you take a look at the logs? There you will find usefull information about the origin of the error, and maybe which file is triggering the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are trying to format the response by using a trait. Correct me if im wrong. If thats the case, you have called the trait function without importing the class in the first place. Then import the class by use keyword.

So the general flow would be as follows you can make adjustments if you are using traits as i assumed.

```
use App\Traits\TraitName;

class YourController extends Controller {
   use TraitName;

   public function foo(){
     $this->TritName($parms);
   }
}
```

And also you dont need to typehint the request in constructor manually hence laravel service container automatically resolves the requests through out the app.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help sir, btw this is my first time on stackoverflow so I am amazed how fast the answer even there's million user asking questions. Yes I already fixed the error thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

in userController of parent controller you have this method? `successResponse`

if not register this method you get exception